# AWS Api Gateway Web Socket Post to $default forbidden

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to get my lambda to post to my aws web socket api and I am getting a Forbidden error message on the post. I have the following setup:

1. A public api configured using  proxy+ to point to a lambda that handles all my routes.
2. A public web socket api that calls the above lambda.

I am testing out connectivity and my lambda correctly receives the $connect, $default and $disconnect events from the web socket api. I am trying to send a test message back to the client on open but receive the Forbidden error on the Post command.

My code is here:

```
    public async Task<ITrWebsocketsContext> SendMessageAsync(UserDefinition userDefinition, string message)
    {
        var connectionIds = GetConnectionIds(userDefinition);
        if (connectionIds != null)
        {
            foreach (var connectionId in connectionIds)
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Sending to {connectionId}");
                    var response = await PostAsync($"https://{suppliedServiceUrl}/@connections/{connectionId}", message);
                    Console.WriteLine($"Sent to {connectionId}: {response}");
                }
                catch (ForbiddenException ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Exception: {SerialisableException.Serialise(ex)}");
                }
                catch (AmazonServiceException ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Exception: {SerialisableException.Serialise(ex)}");
                    RemoveConnection(connectionId);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }

        return this;
    }
```

The call to PostAsync fails.

I think this is a VPC issue as the Lambda is behind a VPC. The VPC is configured with 2 private subnets and 1 public one, with an Internet Gateway. The lambda can access the internet, so the VPC seems to be setup correctly. I also have an endpoint pointing to execute api in my region.

Any ideas on where to go? Do I need a VPC link configured for my lambda to connect to my AWS web sockets api?

Comment: It looks like the execution role in the default route in your websocket api does not have permission to execute the resource you have selected.

Comment: @Ali, that's what I assumed, but the lambda that calls the post command has execute-api:* access for All Resources against InvalidateCache, Invoke and ManageConnections.

Comment: Another reason I have encountered is the role for the lambda execution should also have the access to the VPC.